# Must an isomorphism preserving graph transformation preserve the order of the automorphism group?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory

Let $F$ be some function graph to graph which preserve graph isomorphism.

Example of such $F$ are the line graph, the $k$-subdivision of $G$
and many others.

$F$ need not preserve the order, the degree sequence, the girth,
the size of the maximum independent set and others.

> Q1 Must all $F$ preserve the order of the automorphism group?

According to my limited experiments, the answer is positive.

---

Added: In comments Brendan McKay suggested counterexample for the subdivision transformation and it is the cycle graph.

According to my experiments (modulo errors), subdividing a non-rigid graphs preserves the order of the automorphism group.

> Q2 How to explain this observation?

---

Some tested subdivision examples from sagemath and the "nauty and traces" database:

PetersenGrap, PaleyGraph(73), SRG_100_44_18_20, "had-20" of order 80, "sts-21" of order 70.

Comment: In addition to Martti's example, subdivision does not preserve automorphism group. Consider subdividing a cycle.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thanks, you are right.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Is it coincidence that subdividing random/selected non-rigid graphs preserves the automorphism group?

Comment: I don't understand. A cycle is non-rigid. Do you mean subdividing a rigid graph doesn't seem to create automorphisms?

Comment: @SeanEberhard I mean that a lot of non-rigid graphs (not counting Brendan cycles and small variation) preserve the automorphism group order and I gave sage examples of such graphs. I am interested why in many cases subdivision preserves the order and don't give other order as in Brendan's examples. According to my computations rigid subdivisions are rigid.

Comment: The line graph functor also does not preserve the automorphism group. For example, $L(K_4)$ is the complement of $K_2 \sqcup K_2 \sqcup K_2$, which has automorphism group $C_2^3 \rtimes S_3$, of order $48$.

Comment: Although Q1 itself was too naive, it seems to be a source of somewhat interesting questions to take a given injective functor $F$ from graphs to graphs and ask for which graphs $F:\operatorname{Aut}(G) \to \operatorname{Aut}(F(G))$ fails to be an isomorphism.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Re: line graphs:  for $K_5$ it preserves automorphism. For all the graphs given in the question it also preserves automorphism. I suspect the line graph to have finite families of obstacles which doesn't preserves automorphism like cycles in your answer.

Comment: @SeanEberhard https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53939/connection-between-automorphism-groups-of-a-graph-and-its-line-graph

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems a theorem of Whitney describes when $\operatorname{Aut}(G) \to \operatorname{Aut}(L(G))$ fails to be injective or surjective. Answer: It is injective unless $G$ has a $K_2$ component or at least two isolated vertices. It is surjective unless $G$ has both $W_1$ and $W_2$ as components or a component isomorphic to $W_3$, $W_4$, or $W_5$. Here $W_1, \dots, W_5$ are explicit graphs on at most $4$ vertices, namely $W_1 = K_{1,3}$, $W_2 = K_3$, $W_3 = $ a triangle with a pendant edge, $W_4 = K_{1,1,2}$, and $W_5 = K_4$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Do you happen to have opinion about this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449492/hard-instances-for-this-graph-isomorphism-algorithm-based-on-powers-of-weighted

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer to the follow-up question about automorphisms of a subdivision.

Suppose $G$ is a connected graph which is not $2$-regular. Let $G^{(k)}$  be the $k$-subdivision of $G$, i.e., the graph obtained by replacing each edge with a path of length $k$. Then $\operatorname{Aut}(G^{(k)}) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(G)$.

*Proof:* Clearly every automorphism of $G$ uniquely extends to $G^{(k)}$. Conversely, let $\alpha \in \mathrm{Aut}(G^{(k)})$ and let $v_0 \in V(G) \subseteq V(G^{(k)})$ be a vertex of degree $d(v_0) \ne 2$. Since the vertices introduced by subdivision all have degree $2$, $\alpha(v_0)$ must again be a vertex of $G$. Since the vertices of $G$ are precisely those such that $d_{G^{(k)}}(v,v_0)$ is divisible by $k$, $\alpha$ preserves $V(G)$ and induces an automorphism of $G$ (whose unique extension is $\alpha$).

So subdivision can introduce automorphisms only if $G$ has a connected component which is $2$-regular, i.e., either a finite cycle or a bi-infinite path.

Comment: Thanks. I am not good at group theory, but doesn't this construction gives infinitely many groups of given order? (The orders of $G$ and $G^k$ are different).

Comment: @joro They are only different as permutation groups. As abstract groups they are the same.  For any abstract group there are infinitely many permutation representations, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

If you send a graph to two disjoint copies of the same graph, you get a transformation sending isomorphic graphs to isomorphic graphs (in fact, you get an endofunctor on the category of graphs), but this does not preserve the order of the automorphism group.

Comment: Thanks, this works.